# How to cast exception object to stdClass?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, exception

Sup guys. I'm using ajax to load in a bunch of data with php. Sometimes exceptions go uncaught. This generates some error messages which javascript cannot parse (because it's expecting json). This crashes the page, that's not cool. So I'm building a custom exception handler. Basically it should just json_encode the Exception object. But json only works on objects of type stdClass. So here's the actual question:

How do you cast an exception object to stdClass, so that I can json_encode it? I've tried all the naive stuff I could think of, like

`(stdClass) $ex` and `(Object) ((Array) $ex)`

And yeah, I know that exceptions shouldn't be uncaught to begin with, but it's more like a development feature. It makes debugging less painful ;-)

Thanks!

Comment: I would think the proper way to do it would be to catch the exception and use that to build your return object. Let JSON encode it and pass it back to the client.

Comment: `json_encode` can encode any object. It doesn't work with `Exception` because `Exception` doesn't have any public variables. But you can create your own class/array inside your exception handler and output it to the browser.

Comment: Yea, you are completely right now that I think about it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. PHP doesn't support object casting.
2. Using exceptions handler in this case is an horrible idea, especially when all you have to do is:

   ```
   try {
       // Current code here, including other try-catch blocks
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       // handle uncaught exception
   }
   ```
3. When error occurs you should setup response correctly. Set Response Code to 500 (Internal Server Error) so JavaScript could easly handle that.
4. `Exception` object provides only `getMessage()` and `getCode()` methods that could be usefull, so response body could be generated like so:

   ```
   $responseBody = json_encode(array(
     'message' => $e->getMessage(),
     'code'    => $e->getCode()
   ));
   ```

Comment: Thanks, you pretty much answered all my questions. I'm not just worried about exceptions, but also errors. These things can occur not so obviously as exceptions. Like when a mysql query fails, or you divide by zero.

Comment: Use [PDO](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for database connection - it supports exceptions. Using custom error handler might be a solution, however your code shouldn't throw any error.

Comment: +1, however php does support casting an exception to a stdClass: $x = new Exception("foo"); $x = (object)(array)$x; so you _could_ serialize it, not that one could of course :)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set a custom error handler and make shure when you echo them to the browser not to send 200 header code , that way you can deal with errors in you're js way elegant .

Other options would be to use ob_start , or a big try catch ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a simple function to do it for you (turn an object to an associative array, bypassing access restrictions):

```
function obj2array($object) {
    $r = new ReflectionObject($object);
    $params = array();
    foreach ($r->getProperties() as $prop) {
        $prop->setAccessible(true);
        $params[$prop->name] = $prop->getValue($object);
    }
    return $params;
}
```

Then to encode it:

```
$json = json_encode(obj2array($e));
```